# The difference between the LV state "inactivate"/"active" in Linux

Tags: linux

We know Linux LV has active and inactive status. What's the difference between these two status?

Comment: Inactive logical volume can not be mounted, for example. LVM documentation provides more information, though I hate to point you just to read the manual.

Comment: Besides the inactive LV cannot be mounted, is there any other difference? Like if there is any potential issue to the whole system if a LV is in active or inactive state? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...I google-d a lot these days and also referred to some books and documents, 
1. If a LV is in active state, but not in a mount state, it can be seen by the Kernel, or
   Kernel processes/threads can still use this LV.
2. If a LV is in inactive state, it cannot be available by the Kernel.

Hope that helps. Thanks.